# Array Formula - Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, string-formatting, array-formulas

I have botched out a script I found on Google referring to `array_constrain`. The script should automatically fill the cell with the format `S-"date"-001` in which will increment every time a new row is populated. The problem is the result doesn't display the letter S but the number zero. It displays as `0-06112020-001` where as it should be `S-06112020-001`. I've included the script below:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A:A),IF(ROW(A:A)=1,"Bug No.",TEXT(ROW(H:H),"S-")&TEXT(A1:A,"ddmmyyy")&TEXT(ROW(H:H)-1,"-000")),)),500,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(INDEX({"Bug No."; IF(A2:A="",,
 "S-"&TEXT(A2:A, "ddmmyyyy")&TEXT(ROW(H2:H)-1, "-000"))}), 500, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your formula to

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A:A),IF(ROW(A:A)=1,"Bug No.","S-"&TEXT(A1:A,"ddmmyyy")&TEXT(ROW(H:H)-1,"-000")),)),500,1)
```

and see if that helps?